# How can I extract values from double[,] in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, double, refactoring, extract

I have the following array:

```
 private static readonly double[,] positionsOfCustomer = new double[,] {                    
        {47.645892, -122.336954},   // Gasworks Park
        {47.688741, -122.402965},   // Golden Gardens Park
        {47.551093, -122.249266},   // Seward Park
        {47.555698, -122.065996},   // Lake Sammamish Park
        {47.663747, -122.120879},   // Marymoor Park
        {47.857295, -122.316355},   // Meadowdale Beach Park
        {47.530250, -122.393055},   // Lincoln Park
        {47.503266, -122.200194},   // Gene Coulon Park
        {47.591094, -122.226833},   // Luther Bank Park
        {47.544120, -122.221673}    // Pioneer Park
    };
```

I'd prefer to name the values rather than use comments, so I try using Visual Studio to extract the values like:

```
 private static readonly object gasworksPark = { 47.645892, -122.336954 };
 // etc.

 private static readonly double[,] positionsOfCustomer = new double[,] {
        gasworksPark,   
        // etc.
    };
```

But this results in at least two errors:

> 1. Can only use array initializer expressions to assign array types.  Try a new expression instead.
> 2. A nested array initializer is expected.

How can I extract these values in a way the compiler will understand?

Comment: Define "*extract*"

Comment: I am not on my pc atm, but rather than initiating the field, can you try making calling a static method that adds the value? Method will need to check or will always adds when called multiple times.

Comment: @MichaelRandall, Remove or take out.  As I illustrate above, I want to _name_ the values, rather than use comments to describe them (c.f. "Clean Code")

Comment: Maybe you can just use a dictionary ? or an array of tuple

Comment: @Mocas, I don't want to create a function, I just want to extract the values.

Comment: @MichaelRandall, Are you saying it would be impossible to both extract the values and keep the data type as `double[,]`?

Comment: I would use a dictionary in this case then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to achieve this with a `Multidimensional Array`, but this is achievable with a `Jagged Array`:

```
private static readonly double[] gasworksPark = { 47.645892, -122.336954 };
private static readonly double[] goldenGardensPark = { 47.688741, -122.402965 };
// etc.

private static readonly double[][] positionsOfCustomer = new double [][]{
    gasworksPark,
    goldenGardensPark
};
```

Comment: That definitely could help since I am thinking about making that change (since I'm getting some warnings suggesting I do so), but I'm curious whether it can work for `double[,]` so I'm not ready to accept the answer just yet.  But cheers!

Comment: I think the problem with Multidimensional Arrays is that it must specify the exact number of columns, which you can't guarantee when initializing an array into it. Jagged Arrays doesn't have this concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
private Dictionary<Name, Tuple<double, double>> names = new Dictionary<Name, Tuple<double, double>>
            {
                { Name.gasworksPark, new Tuple<double, double>( 47.645892, -122.336954 ) },
                { Name.goldenGardensPark, new Tuple<double, double>( 47.688741, -122.402965 ) }
            };

private enum Name
{
gasworksPark,
goldenGardensPark
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
private static readonly double[,] gasworksPark =  {{ 47.645892, -122.336954 }};
private static readonly double[,] goldenGardensPark = {{ 47.688741, -122.402965 }};
//etc...
private static readonly object[] positionsOfCustomer =
{
    gasworksPark, 
    goldenGardensPark,
    //etc
};
```

Comment: But then whenever I need to use positionsOfCustomer as a double[,], I would need to cast it.  :-(  @Hayden's answer is closer to what I am looking for but, thanks!  :-)